# Draw Canvas is not Working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

> I'm trying to Draw a *Canvas* using JavaScript ... but it's not working .. Can anybody help me on this? ..I'm trying to Build a Flappy bird with HTML 5 and JavaScript .. but this Code is not Working ..
>
> Pastebin Code: http://pastebin.com/uEXVx89k

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <title>FlappyJS</title>

    <script src="sprite.js"></script>

    <style>
    canvas {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sprite.js"></script>
<script>

var canvas,
ctx,
width,
height,

frames = 0,
score = 0,
best = 0,

currentstate,
states = {

    Splash:0 , Game: 1 ,Score:2
},

bird = {},
pipes = {};

function main(){

    canvas      = document.createElement("canvas");
    width       = window.innerWidth;
    heigth      = window.innerHeight;   


        if (width >= 500) {
            width  = 320;
            heigth = 480;
            canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000";
        }

        canvas.width    = width;
        canvas.height   = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        document.body.appendChild(canvas);



}

function run(){

}
function update(){

}
function render(){


}

main();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Note: I'm a Noob in JavaScript .

I need to Draw a Canvas like the image [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwmnvn04/

You have a typo.

First you declare it like this:

```
heigth      = window.innerHeight;
```

and then (still correct I guess despite spelled wrong for context):

```
  heigth = 480;
```

but then when you call it to determine height of canvas you spell it properly:

```
  canvas.height   = height;
```

Comment: heigth      = window.innerHeight;

Comment: Yeah but then:  canvas.height   = height;